# ejb poller always triggers at every 30 seconds

Tags: ejb-3.0, weblogic-10.x

I have created EJB 3 Timer  and it is deployed into weblogic cluster. The createTimer parameters are createTimer(1000, 20000, null);
This  should create recurring timer for every 20 seconds. But the timer is always created every 30 seconds. I even changed the intervalDuration  to 40 and 50 seconds but the timeout method is always triggered every 30 seconds.

Below are the entry from WEBLOGIC_TIMERS table
1@@OSBNode2_1355845459844   (BLOB)  1355846770914   1000    TimerearTimerTest.jarTimerTest  OSBDomain   OSBCluster

Below are the entry from ACTIVE table
timer.1@@OSBNode2_1355843156331 -96726833478167425/OSBNode2 OSBDomain   OSBCluster  18-DEC-12
service.TimerMaster 8866906753834651127/OSBNode1    OSBDomain   OSBCluster  18-DEC-12
service.SINGLETON_MASTER    8866906753834651127/OSBNode1    OSBDomain   OSBCluster  18-DEC-12

Can anyone help me to investigate why the timer always triggers every 30 second instead of my intervalDuration value?

Below is the EJB ----->>

```
    package com.timertest;
import java.util.*;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.*;

@Stateless(mappedName = "TimerTest")
public class TimerTest implements TimerTestRemote
{
    @Resource
    private SessionContext ctx;

  @Override
  public void createMyTimer()
    throws EJBException
  {
        ctx.getTimerService().createTimer(1000, 20000, null);
  }

    @Timeout
    public void timeout(Timer timer) 
    {
        System.out.println("-> Timed Out ..."+ new Date());

    }
}


Below is the and weblogic descripor-------->>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-ejb-jar
    xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-ejb-jar"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-ejb-jar http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-ejb-jar/1.2/weblogic-ejb-jar.xsd">
    <wls:weblogic-enterprise-bean>
        <wls:ejb-name>TimerTest</wls:ejb-name>
        <wls:stateless-session-descriptor>

            <wls:stateless-clustering>
                <wls:home-is-clusterable>true</wls:home-is-clusterable>
                <wls:home-load-algorithm>round-robin</wls:home-load-algorithm>
                <wls:stateless-bean-is-clusterable>true</wls:stateless-bean-is-clusterable>
                <wls:stateless-bean-load-algorithm>round-robin
                </wls:stateless-bean-load-algorithm>
            </wls:stateless-clustering>
            <wls:business-interface-jndi-name-map>
                <wls:business-remote>TimerTestRemote</wls:business-remote>
                <wls:jndi-name>TimerTest</wls:jndi-name>
            </wls:business-interface-jndi-name-map>
        </wls:stateless-session-descriptor>
        <wls:enable-call-by-reference>false</wls:enable-call-by-reference>
        <wls:jndi-name>TimerTest</wls:jndi-name>
    </wls:weblogic-enterprise-bean>
    <wls:timer-implementation>Clustered</wls:timer-implementation>
</wls:weblogic-ejb-jar>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the direct answer, but might help to avoid such condition.

---

Timers are persistent by default, so you have to cancel the previous timers before starting new ones.

Also, you can provide `info` while creating timer object instead of passing `null`, may be string identifier. It will later help to identify which timer had timed out or to cancel it in case of multiple timers in the system.

Creating timers & restarting the application multiple times, there are several such timers having same `info`, but are having different `hashCode`. So they don't overlap & are created new each time.

You can get timers by `ctx.getTimerService().getTimers()` & cancel by iterating over them.

**Edit :** I have replicated the scenario & have faced similar issue. I have debugged & it happens when there are multiple previous timers active for the same interval, which aren't being cancelled.

You try below code, I have tried & it resolved the issue.

```
for(Timer t : timerService.getTimers())
    t.cancel();  //-- Cancel timers before creatimng new one
ctx.getTimerService().createTimer(1000, 20000, null);
```

Excerpt from documentation :

> intervalDuration - If expiration is delayed (e.g. due to the interleaving of other method calls on the bean), two or more expiration notifications may occur in close succession to "catch up".

Comment: Hi Nayan,Thanks for your response.. The issue I am having is the time is always triggered at every 30 seconds. The intervalDuration   given while creating the time is completely ignored...  Can you pls let me know why intervalDuration   is not reflected.  I even cleared the tables and redeployed the time but still it occurs only every 30 seconds

Comment: @EswaramoorthyBabu I have eidted post based on your comments, refer edit part

Answer (score 0):

**You can use a different style (annotations). See below:**

```
    @Schedule(hour = "*", minute = "*",second = "*/40")
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    @Lock(LockType.WRITE)
    @AccessTimeout(1000 * 60 * 60)//1 Hour...//Concurrent Access is not permitted...
```